# SQL Server UPDATE and SET Using a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

I need to fill a new column "Better_test" with data generated from a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT [User Organization], RIGHT([User Organization], LEN([User Organization]) - CHARINDEX(',', [USER ORGANIZATION])) AS Better_test
FROM Logins
```

The code below gives me the this error:
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

```
UPDATE Logins
    SET Better_test = ( SELECT [User Organization], RIGHT([User Organization], LEN([User Organization]) - CHARINDEX(',', [USER ORGANIZATION]))
    FROM Logins
```

Comment: Don't use a subquery here. That subquery returns more than 1 row. And more than 1 column. What in the world????

Comment: Why are you doing an update here? You're just going to have to run that update again every time a row is added or changed. This could be a simple computed column (in the table, in a view, in the query, etc). The data is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, particularly one returning two values.  Also, the `FROM` is unnecessary:

```
UPDATE Logins
    SET Better_test = RIGHT([User Organization], LEN([User Organization]) - CHARINDEX(',', [USER ORGANIZATION]);
```